# If and Else if Statement

Tags: objective-c, ios, calculator, if-statement

Im wondering why this code won't work. It's for a calculator :)
I need the symbol (banana) to be recognised by the calculator and to use either +,- according to what the user inputs.

```
NSString *list = [Sum_TextField text]; 
NSArray *listItemsArray = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
int batman = [[listItemsArray objectAtIndex: 0] intValue]; 
NSString *banana = [listItemsArray objectAtIndex: 1];
int joker = [[listItemsArray objectAtIndex: 2] intValue];
{

    Calculator* calc = [[Calculator alloc] init];
    [calc setNum1:batman];
    [calc setNum2:joker];
    if ((banana = @"-"))
    {
        [calc minus];
    }
    else if ((banana = @"+"))
    {
        [calc add];
    } 

    [Answer_TextField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [calc answer]]];  
}
}
```

Comment: At the very least you need to use `==` for testing equality.

Comment: You need isEquals (or something similar) function. You are currently assigning `@"+"` to banana.

Comment: Note that the compiler would have warned you about your use of `=`, but you put in a double-parenthesis, explicitly turning off the compiler warning. Be very careful turning off compiler warnings this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you want to do this:

```
 if ([banana isEqualToString:@"-"])
 {
     [calc minus];
 }
 else if ([banana isEqualToString:@"+"])
 {
     [calc add];
 }
```

Comment: I actually love you just saying <3

Comment: Heh, why? :P Do you know me or do you just like my answer? :P

Comment: I liked your answer, works perfectly :) and very quick answer aswell. thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. :) Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer too ;)

Answer (score 2):

To judge whether NSString is equal, you must use `[@"AAAA" isEqualToString : @"BBBB"]`. You can not use `==` , because they are not in the same address of the memory .

Comment: @DavidMurray you can not edit it like this "[@"AAAA" isEqualToString : @"BBBB"]". because my AAAA and BBBB is a NSString *.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is assignment. It has absolutely nothing to do with comparison.

`==` is comparing the 2 expressions and see whether they are equal. This can be used to compare integral types (such as `enum`, `char`, `int`, `short`, `long`, `long long`, `BOOL`) or reference (check whether 2 pointers are pointing to the same object). Note that 2 pointers can point to 2 different object which contains the same value inside, but `==` will compare them as different. (Floating point type such as `float` and `double` requires a bit different method to compare equality).

As a method to preempt confusion between `=` and `==`, for equality testing with `==`, some people put the value on the left hand side, and the variable on the right hand side (e.g. `2 == variable`). If they happen to mistype `==` to `=`, the compiler will complain.

If you want to compare the content of 2 objects, in this case is `NSString`, you should search for `isEquals` type of function. For `NSString`, you should use `isEqualToString` if you want to compare whether the 2 strings have the same content.